# Calculating 'most selected value' in columns

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to calculate the most selected value of a column just using mysql, but I dont know If this is possible or If I will need to also use php ...

All values are integers rangin form 1 to 12, which are the ids of the selections made in the frontend and the table (id:table) looks like this:

```
id | value_1 (int) | value_2 (int) | value_3 (int)
```

EDIT:

With this I can get the most selected of column 'value_1' :

```
SELECT value_1, count( * ) total
FROM table
GROUP BY value_1
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

How could I get all the most selected values in the tree columns (value_1 | value_2 | value_3) in single SQL sentence?

---

Following the duplicated quiestion link I have also tried with this, but It returns an error:

```
select value_1, count(*) total
from (
    select @r := if(total>@r,total,@r) maxcount, value_1, total
    from (select @r:=0) initvars, (
        select value_1, count(*) total
        from table
        group by value_1
    ) X ) Y
where total = @r

MYSQL ERROR : #1140 - Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, didnt know the meaning of 'modal averages', but now is quite clear! 
Still, I dont know how to do the sentence for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify to users that read through this post I managed to do it but using also PHP. It would be nice to do it with just once MYSQL sentence but I couldnt figure out how to do that :

```
$array_sql = array("value_1", "value_2", "value_3");

//Loop
foreach($array_sql as $val){
    $SQL =  "
    SELECT $val, count( * ) total
    FROM table
    GROUP BY $val
    ORDER BY total DESC
    LIMIT 1
    ";

    ${'result_'.$val} = mysql_query($SQL) or die(mysql_error());//$result_mvp

}

//results for value_1
$row_1 = mysql_fetch_array($result_value_1);
$val1 = $row_1['total']; // Most selected option for value_1

//results for value_2
$row_2 = mysql_fetch_array($result_value_2);
$val2 = $row_2['total']; // Most selected option for value_2

//results for value_3
$row_3 = mysql_fetch_array($result_value_3);
$val3 = $row_3['total']; // Most selected option for value_3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, 
    COUNT(val1)As 'First Value', 
    COUNT(val2)As 'Second Value', 
    COUNT(val3)As 'Third Value'
FROM alez
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id DESC
```

The ID with the highest number selected will occur first. Then they will be sorted from highest to lowest based on the number that was selected the most.

Comment: This doesnt seem to work, what Im trying to do is getting the most selected value on each column.